# SOAP Web Service with Custom Class Argument in Java 8 and Glassfish 5

Tags: java, soap, glassfish

I was trying to develop a Soap Service with Custom Class...
But, I can't to check de WSDL generated.

```
package org.bz.soap.ws;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import org.bz.soap.api.models.Empleado1;

@WebService
public interface IWebService {
    
    @WebMethod
    void create(Empleado1 empleado1);
  
    @WebMethod
    int sumar(int a, int b);

}
```

Now the implementation source code

```
package org.bz.soap.ws;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import org.bz.soap.api.models.Empleado1;

import org.bz.soap.api.models.service.IEmpleadoService;

@Stateless
@WebService(endpointInterface = "org.bz.soap.ws.IWebService")
public class WebServiceImpl implements IWebService {

  @Inject
  IEmpleadoService empleadoService;

  @Override
  public void create(Empleado1 empleado1) {
    System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName().concat("  create"));
  }

  @Override
  public int sumar(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
  }

}
```

The POJO class with the packages

```
package org.bz.soap.api.models;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Empleado1 implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private Long id;
    private String nombres;
    private String tipoDocumento;
    private String numeroDocumento;
    private Date fechaNacimiento;
    
    public Empleado1() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombres() {
        return nombres;
    }

    public void setNombres(String nombres) {
        this.nombres = nombres;
    }

    public String getTipoDocumento() {
        return tipoDocumento;
    }

    public void setTipoDocumento(String tipoDocumento) {
        this.tipoDocumento = tipoDocumento;
    }

    public String getNumeroDocumento() {
        return numeroDocumento;
    }

    public void setNumeroDocumento(String numeroDocumento) {
        this.numeroDocumento = numeroDocumento;
    }

    public Date getFechaNacimiento() {
        return fechaNacimiento;
    }

    public void setFechaNacimiento(Date fechaNacimiento) {
        this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
    }

}
```

I was deploying in glassfish

http://localhost:8080/WebServiceImplService/WebServiceImpl?wsdl

The WSDL file:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<!--  Published by JAX-WS RI (http://jax-ws.java.net). RI's version is Metro/2.4.0 (wsit240-7e98ff4; 2017-08-03T21:19:54+0200) JAXWS-RI/2.3.0 JAXWS-API/2.3.0 JAXB-RI/2.3.0 JAXB-API/2.3.0 svn-revision#unknown.  -->
<!--  Generated by JAX-WS RI (http://javaee.github.io/metro-jax-ws). RI's version is Metro/2.4.0 (wsit240-7e98ff4; 2017-08-03T21:19:54+0200) JAXWS-RI/2.3.0 JAXWS-API/2.3.0 JAXB-RI/2.3.0 JAXB-API/2.3.0 svn-revision#unknown.  -->
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://ws.soap.bz.org/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://ws.soap.bz.org/" name="WebServiceImplService">
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://ws.soap.bz.org/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/WebServiceImplService/WebServiceImpl?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="create">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:create"/>
</message>
<message name="createResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:createResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="sumar">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:sumar"/>
</message>
<message name="sumarResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:sumarResponse"/>
</message>
<portType name="IWebService">
<operation name="create">
<input wsam:Action="http://ws.soap.bz.org/IWebService/createRequest" message="tns:create"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://ws.soap.bz.org/IWebService/createResponse" message="tns:createResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="sumar">
<input wsam:Action="http://ws.soap.bz.org/IWebService/sumarRequest" message="tns:sumar"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://ws.soap.bz.org/IWebService/sumarResponse" message="tns:sumarResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="WebServiceImplPortBinding" type="tns:IWebService">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<operation name="create">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="sumar">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="WebServiceImplService">
<port name="WebServiceImplPort" binding="tns:WebServiceImplPortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/WebServiceImplService/WebServiceImpl"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

**Why, Is not described the complete POJO class?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wsdl uses the following import:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://ws.soap.bz.org/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/WebServiceImplService/WebServiceImpl?xsd=1"/>
```

And part of your schema is in another xsd file that can be accessed here - `http://localhost:8080/WebServiceImplService/WebServiceImpl?xsd=1`